Why are my lead acid battery impedance results at different frequencies so similar?
I have six UPSes, each with three strings of 34 blocks off GNB Sprinter XP12V3000. These are connected to a BMS, a PowerShield system for each UPS.
For the last year, many of these blocks have risen over and above the 150% of baseline impedance which I understand is a marker that the batteries are becoming unreliable and need to be replaced. For various reasons this hasn't happened, and the latest problem is the rest of the engineering team said that since the battery monitoring systems are new to us, we have to verify the results via manual testing, using a Hioki battery tester.
I am not really a battery expert but I have looked into this previously and understood the Randles model was a good analogy to understand the internals of a lead acid battery, so I had assumed that since the BMS checks for impedance at 220 Hz and the Hioki at 1kHz, that the results would be incomparable.
Much to my surprise, the results have came in and are actually within the +-5% described by PowerShield.
If the circuit alludes to the fact that a capacitance is in parallel with much of the resistance, why are the test results at 220 Hz and 1 kHz so similar?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randles_circuit
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dirk-Uwe-Sauer/publication/260019892_Impedance-Based_Modeling_Considering_the_Lead-Acid_Battery_as_an_Example/links/56c6457608ae03b93dda52c5/Impedance-Based-Modeling-Considering-the-Lead-Acid-Battery-as-an-Example.pdf

The results for the two frequencies are similar because the capacitive reactive portion of the battery impedance is orders of magnitude larger than the resistance at those frequencies.
